# Defining the addition of systems of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

In the book Matrices and Linear Algebra by Hans Schneider and George Philip Barker, I encounter the exercise of adding two systems of linear equations.

Let the first system be:

$$\begin{cases} a_{11}x_1 +a_{12}x_2 = y_1\\a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 = y_2 \end{cases}$$

and the second system be:

$$\begin{cases} b_{11}x_1 + b_{12}x_2 = z_1\\b_{21}x_1 + b_{22}x_2 = z_2 \end{cases}.$$

The sum of these two systems is defined as the system whose first equation is the sum of each system's first equations, and the second equation is the sum of each system's second equations:

sum = $\begin{cases} (a_{11} + b_{11})x_1 + (a_{12} + b_{12})x_2 = y_1 + z_1\\(a_{21} + b_{21})x_1 + (a_{22} + b_{22})x_2 = y_2 + z_2 \end{cases}$

Defining the equation this way would mean that the order in which the equations appear in each system matters, so why do we define the addition as such? What practical use are we trying to get out of this definition?

Answer (score 1):

This is just addition as matrix equations. So the first equation is $Ax=y$, and the second is $Bx=z$. Addition yields
$$
(A+B)x=y+z,
$$
as you wrote. Like adding equations in a field $K$, we can also add equations in $K^n$.

Comment: $(A+B)x = y + z$ would have been the addition of the matrix equations, but the idea in the book was that we particularly define $(A+B)$ in what you wrote to conform to the above way of adding systems of linear equations. That is, if I'm correct, the definition of $+$ in $(A+B)$ follows from the way we add systems of equations, not the other way round. So, why do we define the addition of systems in that way? We could have added the first equation in the first system to the second equation in the second system, in which case, the $+$ in $(A+B)x$ would simply have to be of a different definition

Comment: Write out the matrix equations with $A$ and $B$ as $2\times 2$ matrices with $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$. Then there is absolutely no difference (addition is commutative) to your sum. So we define this in a unique way, by addition of matrix equations, or equivalently $A+B$ as componentwise addition.